# Windows 10 network detection takes forever

Tags: windows, windows-10

When I boot up my windows 10 machine, it takes a fairly long amount of time for the LAN connection to come online (about 30 seconds until I can reach the internet).

Could this have something to do with the way I wired my network wall sockets? I used the legacy wiring scheme to split a CAT6 gigabit cable into 2 100MBit connections for a 2 port wall socket.

What could be the problem and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

- Select the Ethernet adapter in your Network connection list
- Select `Properties` from the context menu
- Click `Configure`
- Select the `Advanced` tab
- Select `Speex & Duplex` from the list and change the value to `100 MBit/s full duplex`